# Mocking restTemplate getForObject

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, resttemplate

My request to rest service:

```
Price[] prices = restTemplate.getForObject("https://sbk02.test.sparebank1.no/sbk/rest/poc1/prices", Price[].class);
```

I am trying to mock it but there are zero interactions with mock. My test code is:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={ "classpath:/spring/engine.xml", "classpath:/spring/beans.xml"})
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesMocksTestContextListener.class})
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class LabbOgLineProcessTest{
    @InjectMocks
    private PriceService priceServiceMock;
    @Mock
    private RestTemplate template;

    @Before
    public void initMocks() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
     public void complete_AllTasks_success() throws Exception{
             when(template.getForObject(eq(PRICES_NAMESPACE), eq(Price[].class))).thenReturn(prices);
             ProcessInstance processInstance = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("process");
             verify(template, times(1)).getForObject(PRICES_NAMESPACE, Price[].class);
    }

}
```

Comment: Try mocking the interface `RestOperations` instead of the class `RestTemplate`. Also, are you sure the template is being injected correctly in the PriceService? Also, try using `eq(...)` or `any()` with the arguments on the verify. Also, can you post the code of the PriceService?

Comment: i guess you should be calling `priceServiceMock` instead of `runtimeService`

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is most likely that your service is not using the mocked RestTemplate but acquires the instance on his own. You could post the code for clarification.

I would go the spring way and use `MockRestServiceServer` to mock interactions with spring `RestTemplate`.

Make sure your service does not obtain a RestTemplate by creating it himself - it should be injected.

The API documentation contains a usage example.

This way you would also test the deserialization of your JSON payload.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/MockRestServiceServer.html